# Why does my file keep getting overwritten?

Tags: java, file-io, gson, bufferedwriter

I have an arraylist (`result_arraylist`) and an using the gson library to convert java objects to JSON and then print it to a text file. Here is my code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
File file = new File(file_path);
FileWriter fWriter;
BufferedWriter bWriter;

try {
     //create the file if it doesn't exist
     if((!file.exists())) {
         file.createNewFile();
     }
     fWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
     bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
     for(int j = 0; j < result_arraylist.size(); ++j) {
         bWriter.write("<!--"); //this and the last string I write to the file is just to separate the objects for when I read the file again
             bWriter.newLine();
         bWriter.write(gson.toJson(result_arraylist.get(j))); //take the object at index j, convert it to JSON and write to file
             bWriter.newLine();
         bWriter.write("-->"); //seperator to denote end of object
             bWriter.newLine();
             bWriter.newLine();
     }
}
catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

What I didn't show here is that this is nested in a larger `for loop` that fills `result_arraylist` with different objects with every iteration.  My problem is that with every iteration of the main `for loop`, the file keeps getting overwritten.

Comment: The code above will not do as you describe.  Either you have only one iteration or you are doing something different to what you expect. I suggest you step through your code in a debugger to see what it is really doing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In that last paragraph OP added that, this whole code in a for-loop and using a seperator to know the each individual json object in that file. Am I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `File` in append mode by passing true to [`FileWriter(String fileName,
          boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) constructor ,So that it wont override the existing content.

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

```
  fWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Comment: Had this problem a few weeks ago, and this is exactly what I did to fix it. +1

Comment: @user3015565 So this means you were only writing one at a time and you needed to append to not clobber the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is in a larger for loop, each time you run this section of code you are opening the file again. Reopening a file defaults to overwriting it.

It would probably be better to open the file once outside of the outer loop and you will avoid this problem.

If you do want to open the file multiple times like you are doing, use the append flag as Suresh said.